# Xamarin.IOS with ikvm

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ikvm

I am trying to use ikvm ( 7.2.4630.5 ) in my xamarin ios ( 9.2 ) project.
Using classes from the ikvm assemblies works fine, but whenever I am trying to use a class from my ikvmc generate assembly which is not a POJO it throws this exception:

```
Could not load type 'IKVM.Internal.AttributeHelper' from assembly 'IKVM.Runtime, Version=7.2.4630.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58'
```

Is this this because ikvm cannot be used in xamarin ios or should I generate my assembly differently ?

Comment: You can not generate assemblies, emit CIL, load assemblies that are not originally in your app bundle, or JIT, etc... on iOS, it is not allowed by Apple due to phone/app security policies. (FYI: On Android you can).

Comment: I am not sure, I understand you correctly, but I am not trying to load assemblies from outside my bundle, all of my assemblies are included in compilation time to the bundle, what I meant is that the ikvm core assemblies work but my generated assembly ( that is included as part of the prodejct dependencies ) doesnt

Comment: IKVM uses dynamic code generation to support fast reflection and thus those features will fail on iOS... There are forks that have rewritten to use reflection instead that would work... Here is a "OLD" version that works under MonoTouch/Xam.iOS.... https://github.com/samskivert/ikvm-monotouch

Comment: I have already tried ikvm-monotouch but I am facing 2 issues with it.
a. Its omitting most of my classes.
b. I get this error in Visual Studio : Cannot include both 'monotouch.dll' and 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' in the same Xamarin.iOS project - 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' is referenced explicitly, while 'monotouch.dll' is referenced by 'IKVM.Runtime.JNI, Version=0.46.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Comment: That is an old project, it would need upgrade to use Xamain.iOS only. As far as the omitting classes, do you have the linker turned off? If not try that and if it works, than you can create a 'fake' reference list of all your classes that are being omitted and then turn the linker back on to reduce the app size.